# R: sorting function which returns index as well as sorted data

Tags: r, indexing

I'm feeling really dumb for asking this, but: is there an existing function in one of the more common packages which returns both the sorted data and a vector of the source indices?  It's simple enough to write:

```
Rgames> foo <- sample(1:10,10)
Rgames> bar <- sort(foo)
Rgames> bar_index <- sapply(1:10,function(jj)which(foo==bar[jj]))
```

"They call me Stormy^H^H^H^H^Htupid Monday,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obtain the indices easily with:

```
match(bar, foo)
```

---

This command will return a list including both indices and sorted data:

```
list(o <- order(foo), foo[o])
```